# SSL Certificate Causing Issue With Android App

Tags: android, ssl, https

i recently installed An SSL certificate from Comodo on my website. after that i have been facing issues on my android app. the app fails to communicate with the web server. giving an error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

i have contacted my hosting service to look into the SSL chain and they say there is no issue on their end.

i am using this code to redirect all traffic from http to https on my website in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

when i removed this code, everything works fine. 
how can i redirect the website traffic to https without creating issue in the app

Comment: @Reviewers: OP needed to change the URLs from http to https.

Answer (score 1):

`SSLPeerUnverifiedException` ([more here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLPeerUnverifiedException.html))

It notifies you, that you network connection does not trust sertificate our server provide for it. 
You need to extend `SSLSocketFactory` in you mobile app to solve this problem ([as one of ways is to trusting all of sertificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https))

Hope it helps.